# Convert null field to zero before converting to int?

Tags: c#, ado.net

In my program, I'm looping through a datatable to get data from each field.  One line of my code looks like this:

```
int LYSMKWh = Convert.ToInt32(resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["LYSMKWh"]);
```

Basically, I'm just taking the value that's in the cell and converting it to an int32.  I run into a problem, though, when the data in the field is a null.  I get an Invalid Cast error message about not being able to convert a "DBNull" to another type.

So, I know that I can just check the value of the field before I try to convert it by doing something like this:

```
if (resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["LYSMKWh"] == null)
            {
                resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["LYSMKWh"] = 0;
            }
```

But, is there a better way to do this?  Is there something I can do "inline" while I'm trying to convert the value without having to resort to using the `if` ?

EDIT:  I did try using this suggested method:

```
int LYSMKWh = Convert.ToInt32(resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["LYSMKWh"] ?? "0");
```

Unfortunately, I still received the Invalid Cast error message with regards to the DBNull type.  It was suggested that I could have problems using the ?? operator if the types on either side were different.

Also, since I have complete control over the data that I'm building my datatable with, I changed it so that no null values would be written to any field.  So, that pretty much negates the need to convert a null to an int32, in this case.  Thanks for all the advice, everyone!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var LYSMKWh =
    resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["LYSMKWh"].Equals(DBNull.Value)
    ? 0
    : Convert.ToInt32(resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["LYSMKWh"]);
```

Comment: This actually worked pretty good for me.  I tried using the examples below with the ?? operator, but I still ended up getting the Invalid Cast error message.  From what user CodeNaked said below, problems could occur when using the ?? if the types on either side are different.

Answer (score 9):

use the ?? operator:

```
resultsDT.Rows[currentRow][...] ?? "0"
```

(expecting the field to be a string - if not change the "0")

Answer (score 4):

You may consider using C#'s `??` operator, which checks a value for null and if it's null, assigns a default value to it.

Comment: An example would be `int LYSMKWh = Convert.ToInt32(resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["LYSMKWh"] ?? 0);`

Comment: fell into the same trap - only if the type of resultsDt.Rows[...][...] is int (or any number with auto-conversion from 0) - but then the Convert.ToInt32 would be meaningless - i guess it's a string?

Comment: you are right.. if OP has the control of the database, maybe he can set it to return null, and remove the first part of the code (the one takes and converts to int) completely. it should go well...

Comment: Based on both of your comments, I've changed my code so that when my datatable is being built that no null values are written to any of its fields.  So, now, I don't have to worry about converting a null to an int.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the ?? operator:

```
object x = null;

int i = (int)(x ?? 0)
```

Comment: simple and nice

Answer (score 3):

You can use a custom convert method:

```
public static int ConvertToInt32(object value, int defaultValue) {
    if (value == null)
        return defaultValue;
    return Convert.ToInt32(value);
}
```

You may need overloads that take other types, like string. You may have problems with the `??` operator if the types on either side are different.

Comment: I like this answer.  You're right, I did run into a problem using the ?? operator (I received the same error message as in my OP).

Answer (score 2):

You can replace it with a ternary operator:

```
var rowData = resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["LYSMKWh"];
int LYSMKWh = rowData != null ? Convert.ToInt32(rowData) : 0;
```

Alternatively, the `??` operator could work:

```
int LYSMKWh = Convert.ToInt32(resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["LYSMKWh"] ?? 0);
```

But I think that's less readable.

Comment: I don't know, I kinda like your second example.  I've never used the ?? operator so I'll be interested to check it out.

Comment: My second example would also do an unnecessary conversion from 0 to `int`, which might or might not cause you some performance trouble. I'm not sure what type you expect from resultsDT, so you might have to  put in a "0" instead of just 0 if you are expecting a string, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use extension Method.

```
int LYSMKWh = resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["LYSMKWh"].IfNullThenZero();
```

Create the below class

```
public static class Converter
{
    public static Int32 IfNullThenZero(this object value)
    {
        if (value == DBNull.Value)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if it's `DBNull.Value` instead of `null`:

```
if (resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["LYSMKWh"] == DBNull.Value)
{
    resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["LYSMKWh"] = 0;
}
```

The ternary expression would work like this:

```
var LYSMKwhField = resultsDT.Rows[currentRow]["LYSMKWh"];
int LYSMKWh = LYSMKwhField != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToInt32(rowData) : 0;
```